# JSTL - Print current url including query strings

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

`${requestScope['javax.servlet.forward.servlet_path']}` gets me the right string, but not including parameters that might be set in the url.

Example:

`http://localhost/path/i/want?param=1` should give me a string `/path/i/want?param=1`

I have a feeling this should be done easily but can't figure it out.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It's available by `${requestScope['javax.servlet.forward.query_string']}`.

Answer (score 12):

I have been looking for a while too.

```
<c:set var="req" value="${pageContext.request}" />
<c:set var="baseURL" value="${fn:replace(req.requestURL, req.requestURI, '')}" />
<c:set var="params" value="${requestScope['javax.servlet.forward.query_string']}"/>
<c:set var="requestPath" value="${requestScope['javax.servlet.forward.request_uri']}"/>
<c:set var="pageUrl" value="${ baseURL }${ requestPath }${ not empty params?'?'+=params:'' }"/>
```

Comment: JSTL was complaining about the += in the tertiary operator so I changed to 

<c:set var="pageUrl" value="${baseURL}${requestPath}${not empty params ? '?'+params : '' }"/>